# DomPDF installation via Composer requires PHP <8.2

Tags: php, composer-php, dompdf

I'm trying to install DomPDF to use with my Symfony 6.1.3 project. I am using composer (composer require dompdf/dompdf).
However, it seems like it (some of its dependencies) does not support PHP 8.2.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - laminas/laminas-code 4.6.0 requires php >=7.4, <8.2 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - symfony/proxy-manager-bridge v6.1.0 requires friendsofphp/proxy-manager-lts ^1.0.2 -> satisfiable by
> friendsofphp/proxy-manager-lts[v1.0.12].
> - friendsofphp/proxy-manager-lts v1.0.12 requires laminas/laminas-code ~3.4.1|^4.0 -> satisfiable by
> laminas/laminas-code[4.6.0].
> - symfony/proxy-manager-bridge is locked to version v6.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
>
> You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version
> constraint, e.g. "composer require dompdf/dompdf:*" to figure out if
> any version is installable, or "composer require dompdf/dompdf:^2.1"
> if you know which you need.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content.

On the DomPDF Github page it says that you need version 7.1 or higher.
Am I overseeing something, or would I have to downgrade my php version?

My composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.0.2",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.2",
        "symfony/console": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/uid": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.1.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.1.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.40"
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such version as `dompdf/dompdf` 2.1. Also, `laminas/laminas-code` v4.6 is nearly a year old. Why not update it, and the other outdated packages?

Comment: that laminas/laminas-code is not an existing dependency in my project (see added composer.json).

Comment: Why not try to update it anyways? Most packages require stuff on their own. Also, keep in mind that Symfony 6.1 is EOL since some months